# How to unit test a default constructor class using C# in .net?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, constructor

I have a windows class library project in Visual Studio 2012 and I am trying to test a default constructor.

My constructor is:

```
  public Form()
    {
        Items = new List<IFormItem>();
        Items.Add(new FormItem());
        Items[0].Type = ItemTypes.TextBox;
        Items[0].Text = "User ID";
        Items[0].X = 100;
        Items[0].Y = 100;
        Items[0].Height = 30;
        Items[0].Width = 100;
        Items.Add(new FormItem());
        Items[1].Type = ItemTypes.Button;
        Items[1].Text = "Log In";
        Items[1].X = 130;
        Items[1].Y = 170;
        Items[1].Height = 30;
        Items[1].Width = 70;
    }
```

How will I test this?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetForm()
    {
        Form frm = new Form();

        //what to write here
    }
```

I just want to test constructor invoked or not.

Comment: What do you want to test?

Comment: You should not test constructors, because they are not suposed to have any logic in them.

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen yeah that knowledge would help a lot, as I see no point in testing if you don't know what you want to test...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetForm()
{
    Form frm = new Form(); // the constructor is called here, this is your ACT

    var expectedNumberOfItems = 2;
    var expectedType = ItemTypes.Button;

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedNumberOfItems, frm.Items.Count, "frm.Items.Count");

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedType, frm.Items[0].Type, "frm.Items[0].Type");
    // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably test a couple things:

1. That the `Items.Count` is 2;
2. and that the values are what you'd expect.

So, maybe something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetForm()
{
    Form frm = new Form();

    Assert.AreEqual(2, frm.Items.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual("User ID", frm.Items[0].Text);
    ...
}
```

You'd want to test all of the properties you're setting likely, the above code is just an outline.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you could very well test the constructor, but as there is no business logic in your code there really is no point. If you are just thinking about code coverage, you could assert that the Items collection contains two items. At least you will ensure that nobody tampers with your constructor :)

```
Assert.AreEqual(2,frm.Items.Count);
```